# QGIS: Identify depressions/bluespots in the landscape

Tags: qgis, hydrology

I'm looking for a way to identify depressions/bluespots in the landscape. I've tried using the SAGA tool "Fill sinks (Wang & Liu)" but for some reason all of the SAGA tools are greyed out and as soon as I run them they get an error and can't finish. If the analysis had worked I would then use the Field calculator on the filled DEM to calculate the bluespots/depressions. But since SAGA doesn't work...

I haven't been able to find a solution for this problem so instead I'm now looking for an alternative method of identifying depressions in the landscape where water might accumulate during heavy rainfall for example.

Any suggestions on how to create a map like the one I've added below?

The Saga "Fill" approach I've been trying to use
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRuFfDaZXGk

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the QGIS package, GRASS GIS allows you to do that quite easily. Open GRASS GIS, import your raster (`File -> Import raster data -> Simplified raster import with reprojection [r.import]`), then use the r.terraflow tool (`Raster -> Hydrologic Modelling -> Flow Accumulation [r.terraflow]`) which only needs your terrain raster as an input and will generate a set of outputs (filled elevation raster, flow direction raster, flow accumulation raster etc.). The Flow Accumulation Raster as per the image below will show the areas where water is "ponding" due to depressions in the terrain elevation. It's a raster so you can then use the Raster Calculator in QGIS to apply a threshold below which depressions will be identified.

Please note that before running r.terraflow, you need to configure the region settings to those of your raster which you can do in the GRASS GIS console by running: `g.region rast="your raster name"@"Mapset name"`

[image]